# How to get the i'th item in an iterable object. Django/Python

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

In my Django/Python application I am passing multiple iterable objects from views.py to index.html.
I am essentially trying to make a standard for loop in which you can get an item by its index. Once I am iterating through the first object, how can I get the respective index of another iterable in that same loop?

Conditions: All of the arrays will always be equal in length, but their length will change on a daily basis.

**views.py**

```
name = ['John', 'Kim', 'Tim', 'Jill']
age = ['20', '30', '52', '27']
state = ['IN', 'IL', 'CA', 'TX']
city = ['Muncie', 'Champaign', 'Fresno', 'Dallas']

def index(request):
    args = {'names': name, 'ages': age, 'states': state, 'cities': city}
    return render(request, 'index.html', args)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block Data %}
    {% for name in names %}
        <p>{{ name }}</p>
        <p>{{ age.forloop.counter0 }}</p>
        <p>{{ state.forloop.counter0 }}</p>
        <p>{{ city.forloop.counter0 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I thought I would use 'forloop.counter0' as my index. But it doesn't work that way apparently. Any suggestions on how to achieve this goal?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the lists in the view and unpack them in the template:

```
def index(request):
    data = zip(name, age, state, city)
    args = {'data': data}
    return render(request, 'index.html', args)
```

And then in the template:

```
{% for name, age, state, city in data %}
    {{ name }}
    {{ age }}
    {{ state }}
    {{ city }}
{% endfor %}
```

You could also use objects, or named tuples, with the appropriate attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the "for loop counter". You can use {{ forloop.counter }} index start at 1 or {{ forloop.counter0 }} index start at 0.

```
{% for item in list %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
       Do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```